# Why MacBook deleted my files and left me only with DS_Store?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

Well this is a very awkward situation. I can't understand why my files are missing after reproducing the following steps.

1 - Copy files from Desktop folder and paste into external pen drive.

2 - Paste files into another computer (Windows).

3 - Delete files from pen drive.

Noticed folders are created on Windows, but empty.

However, when going back to OS X, the original Desktop folder holds all sub-folders but with no files too.

There is only a lot of `.DS_Store` files remaining there.

Is there anyway to recover these files?

Could it possibly be a pen drive virus?

Comment: Did you test your method by repeating your actions using different files? My only guess would be that your 'paste' action was actually Cmd/Opt/V rather than Cmd/V, which would move instead of copy.

Comment: If I moved instead of copying, why there are still the folders remaining? It would have moved all stuff.